# Minimax theorem for convex quadratic programming

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, duality-theorems, quadratic-programming

I have a simple and stupid question if I have a convex quadratic optimization problem with polyhedral constraints as follows:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\inf_{x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}} & x^{\top} Ax + b^{\top}x\\
& \text{s.t. } Hx \le h.
\end{aligned}
$$

If I introduce the Lagrange function as below:
$$
\inf_{x\in\mathbb{R}^{n}} \sup_{\beta \ge 0} x^{\top}Ax + b^{\top}x + \beta^{\top}(Hx-h),
$$
under which optimality condition
$$
\inf_{x\in\mathbb{R}^{n}} \sup_{\beta \ge 0} x^{\top}Ax + b^{\top}x + \beta^{\top}(Hx-h) = \sup_{\beta \ge 0} \inf_{x\in\mathbb{R}^{n}}  x^{\top}Ax + b^{\top}x + \beta^{\top}(Hx-h)
$$
holds?

As conditions of Von Neumann's Minimax theorem do not hold here, how should I consider the minimax theorem?

Any hints would be appreciated!

Comment: If $x^TAx+b^Tx$ is convex, you can try using [duality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duality_(optimization)) or the [KKT conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karush–Kuhn–Tucker_conditions)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Lagrange duality works. Found condition in Theorem 4.14 of the book "Convex Analysis and Nonsmooth Optimization" by Dmitriy Drusvyatskiy.